# Improving algorithm and syntax for c# linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, optimization

I've been doing a bit of linq in c# .net 3.5 and feel like I should be able to do the following a little neater.

Is there a way to combine this into a single linq statement.

The conditions are as follows

1. If the list contains an element where count is greater or equal to
   the threshold then we can use the list
2. Order the list by count
3. Order the list by date

I'd also like to add another condition on the count where I could treat all items with a count greater or equal than the threshold the same.  I could do this by limiting the count to the threshold but i'd prefer not to in case the threshold were to be changed.  I'm a bit stumped on how to do this other than temporarily editing the records when I get them from the database and not saving them. i.e with a threshold of 3 the list (1,2,3,4,5) becomes (3,3(4),3(5),2,1) before being sorted by date.

```
var allFaves = m_favouriteRepo.Get(user);

if(allFaves.Any(t => t.Count >= threshold))
{
    var ordered = allFaves
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.SortDate)
                 .ToList();
}
```

Thanks
Neil

Comment: `Any()` returns a boolean.  `!= null` makes no sense.

Comment: Is this linq-to-sql, entity framework, or neither?

Comment: using nHibernate. Sorry about the != null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(allFaves.Any(t => t.Count >= threshold))
{
    var ordered = allFaves
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count>=threshold?threshold:x.Count)
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.DatesHistory)
                 .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Or maybe even `OrderByDescending(x => Math.Min(x.Count, threshold))`, depending on what LINQ provider is being used.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like just the ticket